# How can I wrap text around a partial

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views, word-wrap

I'm trying to wrap the text from a post around a partial, which renders a but is seems the best i can do is get it to do is align right. Any ideas?

```
<%= render "shared/slider" %>
<%= render "shared/calender" %>
<div id="post-1">
<b><%= @post.first.title %></b>
<%= simple_format(@post.first().content) %>
</div>
<script>
  #post-1
  {
    align: right;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the CSS property `float`.

I created a quick demo that shows that applying `float: left` to the element you are trying to wrap the text around will achieve your desired effect.

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/MN5BS/